# Laravel Apache to Nginx HTTPS redirect

Tags: laravel, nginx

I'm migrating a Laravel 4.2 site from Apache to Nginx, and having problems with changing the asset URLs over to HTTPS.

Here's an example of how I'm linking to css files in my blade:

```
{{ HTML::style('css/core.css') }}
```

In my old Apache setup, this rendered as HTTPS in the output:

```
<link href="https://my.site.com/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

In my new nginx setup, however, the page redirects to HTTPS, but all of the internal links (forms, CSS, JS etc) all show as HTTP which causes a load of "mixed content" errors.

```
<link href="http://my.site.com/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Here's my nginx.conf:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name my.site.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/my.site.com.chained.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/my.site.com.key;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4";

        server_name my.site.com;
        root /var/www/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        access_log /var/log/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/_error.log;

        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
        location @rewrite {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
        }
        location ~ \.php {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index /index.php;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download)/(.+)$ {
                root /var/www/public;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

I think I can force Laravel to generate secure URLs setting the $secure attribute on HTML::style method, but it's gonna be a big job to change the whole app for that.

How does Laravel apparently "know" to render HTTPS links in Apache, but not nginx, and is there a simple way to force it globally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does Laravel apparently "know" to render HTTPS links in Apache, but not nginx, and is there a simple way to force it globally?

Apache sets `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` to `on`, which is picked up by `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::isSecure()`.

In your nginx config, `fastcgi_param HTTPS on;` will do the same.

Comment: thanks very much fastcgi_param HTTPS on; It was what I was looking for